# Bash script to extract message id and force send

Tags: bash, shell-script, exim

Managed to get my hands on this:

```
#!/bin/bash

######### Edit here ##########

_mail_user=someone@bob.com # Set this to your email id to receive alerts on mail queue
_limit=100 # Set the limit here

##############################

clear;
_result="/tmp/eximqueue.txt"
_queue="`exim -bpc`"

if [ "$_queue" -ge "$_limit" ]; then
echo "Current queue is: $_queue" > $_result
echo "Summary of Mail queue" >> $_result
echo "`exim -bp | exiqsumm`" >> $_result
mail -s "Number of mails on `hostname` : $_queue" $_mail_user < $_result
cat $_result
fi

rm -f $_result
```

Works like a charm. Now I just have one question for someone slightly more advanced than me. Assuming the queue has exploded with spam, above message will just be in the back of the queue - so we would want to force it to be sent before anything else essentially.
From my understanding, we can use the following to force delivery of one message:

```
/usr/sbin/exim  -M  email-id
```

Anyone here know how I could extract the email-id from the scripts mail function and then run the above command with it?
Something along the lines of:

```
_message_id = "'exiqgrep -f root@hostname'"
/usr/sbin/exim  -M  "$_message_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
exiqgrep -f 'root@hostname' -i | xargs exim -M
```

You can also look at more powerful tool `exipick`.

Comment: I think that will do the trick, thanks - doesnt work fast enough on a small queue though because it insta sends :P